# Identifying the type of adverb

Tags: adverbs

There is a question in which I have to identify the type of adverb. Question sentence is

> The railway station is far off.

What my analysis of the question is

Here **off** is an adverb which means **away from a particular place** and **far** is also an adverb which indicates **the amount/degree** so **far** must be an **adverb of degree/quantity**, but the answer given in my book is **adverb of place**

Please help me clear my doubt

Comment: I'd say that "far away" is a preposition phrase, with "away" as head and "far" as modifier.

Comment: *Far off* is acting adjectivally to *is*, not adverbially. Although you can try to analyze the components of *far off* individually, it seems simpler to think of the phrase as a whole. (It's the equivalent of *distant*.)

Answer (score 1):

It can't be  that "off" means "away from a particular place" in this usage, or

> The railway station is off.

would mean that the station is at a moderate, but not a great distance. But it doesn't mean anything of the sort. If it has any meaning at all, it means "there is something wrong with he station, but I'm not sure what." and that is a completely different use of "off".

I think that "far off' must be considered together, as an adjectival phrase, as the comment by  Jason Bassford suggests. It is giving a characteristic of the station, not modifying any verb.